# Value incrementing by wrong amount using timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

OK, so on form load i call a method that starts a timer, which every tick is suppose to increment an integer value and set a text box field text = to the integer.ToString and for some reason it increment by 4 instead of 1..........

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Starts the Timer >:D
    /// </summary>
    public void StartCounting()
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);
        t.Start();


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is what Happens when the timer ticks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void OnTimerEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBoxActual.Text = currentMinute.ToString();
        currentMinute = currentMinute + 1 ;
    }
```

[image: na]

the number in green is textBoxActual <.<

This is my form load code:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Order o = new Order();
        StartedOrders = o.GetUnfinishedOrders();
        PopulateGrid(StartedOrders, dataGridViewStartedOrders);

        //Set the top row to be some abstract style.
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle iStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        iStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",13,FontStyle.Bold);
        iStyle.Font = f;
        dataGridViewStartedOrders.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle = iStyle;
        dataGridViewStartedOrders.ClearSelection();


        try
        {
            textBoxOrderNumber.Text = "O# " + dataGridViewStartedOrders.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBoxCustomerName.Text = dataGridViewStartedOrders.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBoxTarget.Text = dataGridViewStartedOrders.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBoxActual.Text = "0";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        StartCounting();
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code for currentMinute? i mean decleration and any other usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is always updating by 4, my psychic debugging powers say that you're adding your listener 4 times.

Comment: I agree. Since you aren't instantiating a new timer within your `StartCounting` method, if you invoke the method multiple times, the event gets appended multiple times. @JustinKirk, can you debug and ensure that you do not execute the `StartCounting` method more than once?

Comment: Somehow my 'StartCounting' method got inside a for loop inside of the 'populategrid' method <.<

Comment: is there any reason you're also doing toString and then math on minutes?  why not just keep actual datetime/timespan/etc numeric values around?  admittedly we can't see any of the rest of your code, so there might be a reason...